# How to get rid of Sonar Report message 'File does not end with a newline.'

Tags: sonarqube

I'm integrating Sonar to generate a report for one of Android-Kotlin project.

It's done but it generated the report with Code Smells & most of are related with message "Checks whether files end with a line separator." which are nothing but just a warning message at the end of the file.

Any suggestion how this can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open you `SonarQube` server in browser (default URL is http://localhost:9000/)

2.Perform log in (default login - admin, password - admin)

3.Then go to `Quality Profiles`:

[image: Quality profiles]

4.Copy `Java` profile  and name it as you like:

[image]
Newly created profile will open immediately.

5.Open active `Code Smells` rules:

[image]

6.Search required rule and click `deactivate`:

[image]

7.Go back to `Quality Profile` and set your profile as default:

[image]

In this way you can deactivate any built-in rules, also you can create you own rules, more details you can get from [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules) article.